# PhoneGap gives NSURLErrorDomain error -999

Tags: javascript, cordova

As soon as I dump my code into the `www` folder of my PhoneGap project, I get:

> Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

I'm using the following:

- Mac OSX Lion
- PhoneGap 2.1
- Xcode 4.5
- iOS 6 iPhone Simulator
- Parse SDK (built on BackboneJS)
- jQuery Mobile

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a redirect for location-saving, which isn't really all that useful. Anyhow, that was causing the problem, so a little comment-out did the trick:

```
// resume from last location
// if(window.localStorage.lastLocation) {
//     window.location = window.localStorage.lastLocation;
//     delete window.localStorage.lastLocation;
// }
```

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar error when I upgraded from Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.2 to 2.7.

The problem I hit was that Cordova 2.7 didn't handle client side redirect during startup correctly. My solution was to modified `CordovaLib/Classes/CDVWebViewDelegate.m` to handle the redirect case.

Here is my pull-request:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/57/files

Comment: The bug should have been fixed in PhoneGap 3.0 as indicated by shazron at github.